# Is Hamilton the biggest film acquisition in history?

Tags: cinema-history, film-industry, disney

Coming from an article at [Deadline](https://deadline.com/2020/02/disney-paid-75-million-hamilton-movie-deal-lin-manuel-miranda-largest-film-acquisition-ever-1202849929/) with the headline,

> ### Disney Paid $75 Million For Worldwide Movie Rights To Lin-Manuel Miranda’s ‘Hamilton’; Biggest Film Acquisition Deal Ever?

and then goes onto to say,

> According to sources, Disney beat out other suitors and paid $75
> million for worldwide rights to the show that won 11 Tony Awards in
> 2016, as well as the Pulitzer Prize for Drama. Disney won the deal
> with a commitment for a wide global theatrical release for the 2 hour,
> 40 minute movie, which was shot two weeks before the original cast
> left.
>
> **I can’t think of an acquisition of a finished film that has gone for
> more money than this one. It is, however, a seminal cultural zeitgeist
> event and, as Miranda himself has said, the movie allows people to
> avoid having to pay $500 a seat, which they were before the original
> cast and he moved on. You could hardly call this profligate spending,
> given that when Hamilton finishes its traditional theatrical run, it
> will then become a major title on the Disney+ streaming service.**

So is this the biggest film acquisition in film history?